# Message for (late) answers of new users

Tags: feature-request

Almost all the review items in the Late Answers category are from new users who have the same problem / question as the OP. Can't we have an extra message for new users who answer an old post? Something that says "are you sure you're *answering* this question?" could be helpful, in my opinion.

Comment: I am not sure stupidity factors in, on every other forum on the internet posting your own problem that is very similar on the same thread is standard practice, they just dont realize how different the site is. I also thought that queue only pulled new user late answers, but I could be wrong.

Comment: You probably know it better, but if that's the case, I'd say we don't need the late answers at all, they are included in first posts already (what happens now a lot). I removed the stupid-thing, it was a bit rude indeed. Sorry!

Comment: that is true, the new user queue should catch all of them, I must be in err on that point.